# Scraping AliExpress Images using Goutte

Tags: php, goutte

I'm struggling to scrape a full page of Aliexpress image. It gets all of the alt tags, and the first 8 images.

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Goutte\Client;

$url = "https://www.aliexpress.com/af/tie.html?SearchText=tie";

$client = new Client();

$crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);

$output = $crawler->filter('#hs-below-list-items li div div.img.img-border div a img')->each(function ($node) {

echo '<img src="' . $node->attr('src') . '" alt="' . $node->attr('alt') . '">';

});

var_dump($output);
```

Is this something todo with AliExpress Lazy Loading in the images possible?

Would I need to use something like a headless browser? If so can you please point me in the right direction.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Jake.

Comment: Off-topic but how do you pass slidebar verification when scraping though? I mean after a while of scraping you always get a slidebar to slide to be able to continue, even if I slide it manually I still get error somehow. Would appreciate your comment.

Comment: Off-topic too, is this still working ? I was scraping Aliexpress but since a month its seem to be full js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter for the data attribute itself.

```
$output = $crawler->filter('img.picCore[image-src]')->each(function ($node) {

    echo '<img src="' . $node->attr('image-src') . '" alt="' . $node->attr('alt') . '">';

});
```

JH